# Premiere 6 - how to add black between clips in a sequence automatically

Tags: premiere

We have regular fulfilment jobs for clients which require us to insert a few seconds of black between each clip in a contiguous file. It's not a great deal of effort to do it once or twice but when the jobs are larger, consisting of 50+ short clips, it seems like some time could be saved if there were a way to get the sequence to automatically and consistently add the black clip every time a footage clip was added.

Can anyone think of a clever way to do this? Would handles help here?

Very grateful for any thoughts!

Thanks.

Comment: What OS do you use? Some OS tools might help us to achieve this workflow. Such as Applescript etc. Just brainstorming, because as far as I know, there's no automation possible in Adobe Premiere.

Answer (score 3):

A workflow involving Adobe Bridge is as follows. If you have Premiere Pro, you probably installed Bridge, if not, please do install.

- Put your batch of clips in a folder. I would use a directory structure like `Client Name > Jobs > YYYY_MM_DD > Footage` etc.
- Find your footage in Bridge.
- Select all your footage, then under `Tools` menu select `Batch Rename (Shift + Command (Control) + R`

[image: Tools > Batch Rename]

- In your Batch Rename settings, change destination folder to something like `Renamed`, next to your footage folder (to keep everything organised). Under `New Filenames` just select `Sequence Number`, add 1 and select Three or Four digits. This will rename your files `0001.mov, 0002.mov etc.`

[image: Batch Rename Settings]

- From Premiere, render a black video with a length you wish or a black
  frame with the same resolution and pixel aspect ratio with your
  footage. You will need to duplicate the black footage as much as you
  need. Rename them with Bridge, this time add a letter **a** to the
  end of filename, and rename in the same folder.

[image: Batch Rename Blacks]

- Back in Premiere, import all the footage in your footage folder, including blacks. In your bin panel, sort them by name, they should be sorted in the following order: `0001.mov, 0001a.mov(or png), 0002.mov, 0002a.mov`. Select them all and drag to your timeline. They should be placed as you wish, a video clip followed by a black clip.

If you are using still images as blacks, adjust their default length in Premiere's `Preferences > General > Still Image Default Duration` option.

If the videos are always in the same specs, you can re-use those blacks, by duplicating and renaming again.

Still not the shortest way, but kind of better??